# X11 how to listen real-time moving window events

Tags: c, x11

I can only get events after the window has moved, not while it is moving.

I want to get moving events in real time. Please,what should I do?

```c
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argv, char **agrc)
{
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window w = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, RootWindow(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)), 10, 10, 800, 400, 1, BlackPixel(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)), WhitePixel(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)));
    XSelectInput(dpy, w, StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(dpy, w);
    XEvent event;
    for (;;)
    {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &event);

        if(event.type == ConfigureNotify)
        {
            XConfigureEvent x = event.xconfigure;
            printf("config[%d]{%d,%d,%d,%d}\n", x.window, x.x, x.y, x.width, x.height);
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(dpy, w);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried/Where are you stuck?

Comment: thank. when I moving the window, I can't get the ConfigureNotify event ,until Release the mouse. I want to get it on the move.

Comment: that might be your window manager only actually moving the window only after you released the mouse. Do you see same behaviour with other WMs as well? Your code looks OK to me